# Dependency Injection and project structure for Console applications

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, console-application

I have 4 projects:

**Core (IServer):**

- System
- System.Core

**DependencyResolver:**

- Core
- StructureMap

**Infrastructure (Service):**

- Core
- External dependency

**Console:**

- Core
- DependencyResolver

**Requierements:**

I am trying to use StructureMap only in the DependencyResolver.
Furthermore the Console application should not know anything about Infrastucture.

When I do not want to reference StructureMap on my Console Application I have to build a ServiceLocator.

In the DependencyResolver I have a Bootstrapper that is responsible for calling StructureMap registry stuff (Register)

In my Console application I want to get an instance. For this I need to reference StructureMap. Another way would be to write a little wrapper around StructureMaps resolving methods.

Is there any other better way of decoupling the console from StructureMap?

Comment: Sounds a little over engineered.  What does your code look like?  Why do you need a service locator if your dependency resolver already encapsulates the structure map?

Comment: Have you seen http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: The name dependency resolver is not the best choice in respect what the component is reponsible for. At the moment its only responsibility is to register dependencies. So my question is more about the resolving part of Dependency Injection.

Comment: @PhilBolduc What is the responsibility of the bootstrapper? Register or Resolve or both?

Comment: It is mainly about registration. Resolving is done by the container of your choice (in your case StructureMap).  The registration can stay in your DependencyResolver assembly.  Using Bootstrapper or not, you could use MEF to allow your Console application find your bootstrapping/registration code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While I see a reason for separating IoC register,resolve,release from the implementation of the application, I don't see any reason why the IoC container shouldn't be in the console application (the composition root) and the application implemention in another assembly instead.

That way the console application is very easy:

1. Create the container
2. Load the container configuration
3. Resolve the Application
4. Call run on the application and pass the console arguments along
5. dispose the container when the application exits the run method

With SM it look about like this:

```
public void Main(params string[] args)
{
    using (var container = new Container())
    {
        container.LoadAllConfigurationModules();
        container.AddRegistry<SomeRegistry>();
        container.GetInstance<Application>().Run(args);
    }
}
```

For things you can't create at startup you create a factory interface in your application assembly:

```
interface ISomeFactory { ISomeDependency CreateSomeDependency() }
```

and implement this interface in the console application by injecting the container and use it to resolve the instance. I guess the SM implementation looks like this:

```
public class SomeFactory : ISomeFactory
{
    public SomeFactory(IContainer sontainer) { this.container = container; }
    ISomeDependency CreateSomeDependency() { this.container.GetInstance<ISomeDependency>(); }
}
```

Other IoC container even have the functionallity to implement these interface factories automatically.

Comment: With your solution you have to reference all libraries in the console application. Because the composition root lies directly in the Main class.

Comment: Yes that's correct. But where is the problem? This assembly has exactly one purpose - bootstrapping!

Comment: ah ok. Your second statement is important. That makes sense.